# summing up of difference in timings in json array of angularjs application is going wrong

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have the following array of json objects and function to get total Hours count.

```
$scope.workingHrsList = [
  {   
    "uniqueStartTime": "4.00", //4 AM
    "uniqueEndTime": "16.45"  //4.45 PM
  },
  {   
    "uniqueStartTime": "16.45", //4.45 PM
    "uniqueEndTime": "3.15"  // 3.15 AM
  },
  {   
    "uniqueStartTime": "3.15", //3.15 AM
    "uniqueEndTime": "4.00"   // 4.00 AM
  }
];

var toatlWorkingHrsCnt = getTotalHoursCount();    

 function getTotalHoursCount() {
        var totalHrs = 0.0;
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.workingHrsList .length; i++) {
            totalHrs = totalHrs + (parseFloat($scope.workingHrsList [i]["uniqueEndTime"]) - parseFloat($scope.workingHrsList [i]["uniqueStartTime"]));
            $scope.workingHrsList [i]["diffHrs"] = (parseFloat($scope.workingHrsList [i]["uniqueEndTime"]) - parseFloat($scope.workingHrsList [i]["uniqueStartTime"])) + "";
            console.log("End : " + parseFloat($scope.workingHrsList [i]["uniqueEndTime"]));
            console.log("Start : " + parseFloat($scope.workingHrsList [i]["uniqueStartTime"]));
            console.log("Row Hrs with Index " + i + "  : " + totalHrs);
        }
        console.log("Total Hours : " + totalHrs);
        return (totalHrs);
    }
```

so that I can check

```
if(toatlWorkingHrsCnt == "24.00" ) {
console.log("Payable");
} else {
console.log("Not Payable");
}
```

Even though manually, we can clearly see that the difference in the timings is adding up to 24hrs, but the function is not giving that result. Can any one help me to fix the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using 24hrs format, then try this,

```
$scope.workingHrsList = [
                    {   
                        "uniqueStartTime": "4.00", //4 AM
                        "uniqueEndTime": "16.45"  //4.45 PM
                    },
                    {   
                        "uniqueStartTime": "16.45", //4.45 PM
                        "uniqueEndTime": "3.15"  // 3.15 AM
                    },
                    {   
                        "uniqueStartTime": "3.15", //3.15 AM
                        "uniqueEndTime": "4.00"   // 4.00 AM
                    }
                ];



function getTotalHoursCount() {
        var totalHrs = 0, uEndTime = 0, uStartTime = 0, diff = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.workingHrsList .length; i++) {

            uEndTime   = parseFloat($scope.workingHrsList[i].uniqueEndTime);
            uStartTime = parseFloat($scope.workingHrsList[i].uniqueStartTime);

            //always start greater than end time if not 
            //it means they worked continued for next day, 
            //so we need to 24 hrs with end time
            if(uEndTime > uStartTime){
                diff = uEndTime - uStartTime;
            }
            else{
                diff = (uEndTime + 24) - uStartTime;
            }

            totalHrs += diff;
            $scope.workingHrsList[i].diffHrs = diff;

            console.log("End : " + uEndTime);
            console.log("Start : " + uStartTime);
            console.log("Row Hrs with Index " + i + "  : " + totalHrs);
        }
        console.log("Total Hours : " + totalHrs);
        return totalHrs;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is the way you are handling your time differences. For row[1] your end time is before your start time. So you need to add on 24 hours to account for that. Here is some updated logic for your loop:

```
var row = workingHrsList[i];
var endTime = parseFloat(row["uniqueEndTime"]);
var startTime = parseFloat(row["uniqueStartTime"])

var diff = endTime - startTime;

if(diff < 0) {
  diff += 24;
  console.log("24 hours added");
}

totalHrs += diff;
```

Here is a simple working example.
https://jsfiddle.net/L4oq1p85/